# Filtering in SQL Server table on multiple columns - T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, dense-rank

EDITED
We have a table like below where there are multiple rows with same Name with different Ops

| Deal | Name | Ops |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | A | NULL |
| ABC | A | NULL |
| ABC | B | NULL |
| ABC | B | NULL |
| ABC | B | Default |
| ABC | B | Default |
| ABC | C | NULL |
| ABC | C | NULL |
| ABC | C | Default |
| ABC | C | Default |
| ABC | C | Aggr |
| ABC | C | Aggr |

We need to get rows with Default when both NULL and Default is tagged and Aggr when NULL, Default and Aggr are tagged

Expected output:

| Deal | Name | Ops |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | A | NULL |
| ABC | A | NULL |
| ABC | B | Default |
| ABC | B | Default |
| ABC | C | Aggr |
| ABC | C | Aggr |

We need to get this using a SQL query.

I have tried this one here:

```
WITH PriorityRanking AS
(
    SELECT 
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Deal, Name 
                           ORDER BY 
                              CASE COALESCE(Ops,NULL)
                                  WHEN 'Aggr' THEN 1
                                  WHEN 'Default' THEN 2
                                  WHEN NULL THEN 3
                              END) AS Rnk, 
        *
    FROM 
        Table_name  
)
SELECT Deal, Name, Ops 
FROM
    (SELECT Deal, Name, Ops, 
     FROM PriorityRanking 
     WHERE Rnk = 1)
```

But the rank is set to 1 for NULL values and so the final select is not working properly.

Please suggest what is the best way to get the required data

Comment: `COALESCE(Ops,NULL)` makes no sense; "if Ops is null, then use null". `WHEN NULL` is the same as `= NULL`, which obviously doesn't work

Comment: By the way, for the data as given, you can also select `MIN(Ops)`

Comment: I'm not sure why all current answers decided to replace `DENSE_RANK` with `ROW_NUMBER`, for your sample data it doesn't matter. But be aware a `ROW_NUMBER` will return a single row for each partition, while a `DENSE_RANK` will return ties too. Your question doesn't immediately make it clear which you need. I always prefer `DENSE_RANK`, because I want to know if there is unexpected data. But it all depends on the data and what you are looking to accomplish

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to use `row_number` and coalesce your `NULL` values to be ordered below the other values -

```
with r as (
    select *, Row_Number() over(partition by deal, name order by IsNull(Ops,'x') ) rn
    from t
)
select Deal, Name, Ops
from r
where rn = 1;
```

depending on your *real* data as mentioned you could also simply aggregate:

```
select Deal, Name, min(Ops) Ops
from t
group by Deal, Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

The below logic can work

```
WITH cte1 as
(

Select deal,name,isnull(Ops,'Z') as Col from table
),
cte2 as
(
Select *,row_number() over(Partition by Deal,name order by col) as rnbr from cte1 
)

Select deal,name,case when col='Z' then NUll else Col end as Ops from cte2 where rnbr=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace NULL with a text and sort after that

After changing your data, the basic concept stays valid

But now you need `DENSE_RANK` like you had it in your original question, as SQL SERVER can't handle NULL, so replacing will help

> ```
> WITH PriorityRanking AS
>  (
>  SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY CASE ISNULL(Ops,'NULL')
>                                                                     WHEN 'Aggr' THEN 1
>                                                                     WHEN 'Default' THEN 2
>                                                                     WHEN 'NULL'  THEN 3
>                                                                     END) AS Rnk,*
>  FROM Table_name  
>  )
>  SELECT [Deal], [Name], [Ops] FROM  PriorityRanking WHERE Rnk = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> Deal | Name | Ops    
> :--- | :--- | :------
> ABC  | A    | null   
> ABC  | A    | null   
> ABC  | B    | Default
> ABC  | B    | Default
> ABC  | C    | Aggr   
> ABC  | C    | Aggr
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=37f8a20e647110a341e5ad1194517cd8)*

> ```
> WITH PriorityRanking AS
>  (
>  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY CASE ISNULL(Ops,'NULL')
>                                                                     WHEN 'Aggr' THEN 1
>                                                                     WHEN 'Default' THEN 2
>                                                                     WHEN 'NULL'  THEN 3
>                                                                     END) AS Rnk,*
>  FROM Table_name  
>  )
>  SELECT Deal, Name, Ops FROM PriorityRanking where Rnk = 1
> ```

> ```
> Deal | Name | Ops    
> :--- | :--- | :------
> ABC  | A    | null   
> ABC  | B    | Default
> ABC  | C    | Aggr
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=75b6bd157f23d7a34370a0effd268cf4)*

Comment: Personally, I would not even mention or handle `NULL`, and just use `ELSE 3` instead

Comment: @HoneyBadger as this is only a sample we don't know really the complexity of the case, my answer shows only how to handle the NULL values, there could be hundreds of cases so the upvoted answer wouldn't work.

Comment: Very true. In most cases like this, `NULL` is the least preferred value, but it isn't a given

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question. The table is having multiple rows with same Names and Ops values and we need to select all rows with names NULL and Default (when NULL and Default) and Aggr (when NULL , Default and Aggr)

Comment: there the dense_rank makes much more sense